# Merge current branch into HEAD

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, pull

Master HEAD has a few changes and I'm trying to merge my current local changes with the Head.
Suppose I have conflicting changes. `git` just refuses to `pull`.

It says I have conflicting changes, so in this case I expect it to tell me the files that have conflicts but it expects me to revert my local changes and then pull

```
     Master 
     /    \
  branch1  branch2 (local)
      \
   Master
```

When branch2 tries to commit changes to master fails. What should I do in this case?  Manually copy files to some location, pull and the then use winmerge to merge the files? or is there a better way to to merge?

When I do a `git pull`, it states that - local changes will be overwritten, so stash or commit the changes before pull.

When I `stash` or `commit` the changes, and then `pull` `stash pop` fails stating that the changes in working copy will be overwritten.

BTW, I never see a file with conflicts in either of the cases, even when I try a rebase.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't just copy the files manually; you'll loose your history!

Comment: I see no mention of `git merge`; did you try using that?  I'd suggest you also read this first: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

Comment: Show us the complete output from the failed `git pull` command

Comment: Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting

git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1)

Comment: Git Merge output:                                             git.exe merge    --no-commit master

Already up-to-date.                                                      
Success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the best way to work with GIT is have branches.

**Branch 1**
GIT Commit
GIT PUSH
GIT MERGE master ( to fetch the newer changes)

**Branch 2**
GIT Commit
GIT PUSH

**master**
GIT Merge branch1
GIT Merge branch2

I dont think there any other way. Please correct me if i am wrong?

Is this correct, If yes, in this case working with branches is smooth!

Comment: How do I switch master and branch?  For clarity.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this question is hidden in plain view in the documentation. From `git help merge`:

---

## HOW TO RESOLVE CONFLICTS

After seeing a conflict, you can do two things:

- Decide not to merge. The only clean-ups you need are to reset the index file to the HEAD commit to reverse 2. and to clean up working tree changes made
  by 2. and 3.; `git merge --abort` can be used for this.
- Resolve the conflicts. Git will mark the conflicts in the working tree. Edit the files into shape and `git add` them to the index. Use `git commit` to seal
  the deal.

You can work through the conflict with a number of tools:

- Use a mergetool.  `git mergetool` to launch a graphical mergetool which will work you through the merge.
- Look at the diffs.  `git diff` will show a three-way diff, highlighting changes from both the HEAD and MERGE_HEAD versions.
- Look at the diffs from each branch.  `git log --merge -p <path>` will show diffs first for the HEAD version and then the MERGE_HEAD version.
- Look at the originals.  `git show :1:filename` shows the common ancestor, `git show :2:filename` shows the HEAD version, and `git show :3:filename` shows the
  MERGE_HEAD version.

Comment: I dont see the marked conflicts. Thats what i want to see. Instead GIT PULL just comes out. Does that mean a GIT Merge is required?

Comment: The marked conflicts are inside the conflicted files. Edit the question and include the output from the failed `git pull` command

Comment: Also, see `git status` to see the, uh, status of your working copy and index

Comment: *Also*, actually take a look at `git help merge` and see the section **HOW CONFLICTS ARE PRESENTED**

Comment: I have never seen a file with conflicts in it. The GIT PULL or GIT STASH POP, just notifies me that there are conflicts. but aborts.

Comment: Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting

git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1)